# best way to create Intershop UUIDs

Tags: intershop

As the title states, are there any preferred ways to create UUIDs for Intershop usage (eg. *jobs*)? Do UUIDs need to be specific?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For migrations or manual use of uuids there is an ant task:

```
ES1|...\eserver\...\tools\misc>ant uuid
Buildfile: build.xml
build.environment:
uuid:
createuuid.classpath:
createuuid:
     [echo] Generating an amount of 5 UUIDs...
     [java] UUID: fMsKAB2ZfRcAAAEwtG8luGUc
     [java] UUID: qB8KAB2Z2UQAAAEwtm8luGUc
     [java] UUID: nkgKAB2Z2UUAAAEwtm8luGUc
     [java] UUID: Yg0KAB2Z2UYAAAEwtm8luGUc
     [java] UUID: gGcKAB2Z2UcAAAEwtm8luGUc
```

Answer (score 3):

UUIDMgr is deprecated. Please use 
`com.intershop.beehive.core.capi.util.UUIDGenerator` instead.

```
@Inject
private UUIDGenerator uuidGenerator;
...
String uuid = uuidGenerator.createUUIDString();
```

Comment: Another possibility to just create some UUIDs to use in DBInit configuration is to call ant uuid in tools/misc of the deploy server.

Comment: Database contains a function 'sf_create_uuid' if you need a UUID for migration purposes.

Answer (score 3):

If you need to create the UUID in a pipeline you can just use the `CreateUUID.pipelet`.

If you want to create a UUID in your custom Java code you can create it like this (this code is just a copy from the CreateUUID pipelet):

```
@Inject
private UUIDGenerator uuidGen;

String uuid = uuidGen.createUUIDString();
```